# Automate windows login using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am try to Develop a application that can control a PC using SMS with internet. also i turn on the PC power with a cell phone. but After i turn on the PC it will ask for username & password! I store this information on a local database (Eg:MS ACCESS). how can i get that username & password then log in to PC using a VB.NET Program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to read the database your application will need to be already running before the user is logged in, like a system service. Can you do all the stuff you want to do within this service without logging in actually? This would spare you the horrors of...

[Gina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication). At least up to XP to log into your computer without entering the password on the keyboard you can store the credentials in the registry (remove password login, autologin every time) or implement a custom gina.dll that can "simulate" a user. VB.Net cannot be used to write a custom gina.dll as far as I know, you will need to use C/C++ for this.

Added: At least in theory you could simulate keypresses via usb, remote control your local machine or something other to simulate a keyboard, anything might be better than Gina ; )